# Why is the data set from one list view being displayed in another list view?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a view pager with 2 list views on different pages of the pager. I am having a very strange problem where if i set one list view with a custom adapter and data set, the other list view although with a different data set and adapter also shows the same data when i swipe to its page.

Has any one else encountered such a problem or could someone suggest what I could possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: ... Not much to go on. It's likely you're not doing what you think you are with the data.

Comment: are you using fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using findviewbyid to get the object of the list view somewhere that runs while the other listview is being drawn for caching

please try to place your code in instantiate item and keep in mind that it's best to inflate a view in instantiateItem rather than to use current widgets on the viewpager original layout ( personally i think it's wrong)

take a look at https://github.com/Shereef/ViewPagerPlusExpandableList and see my project and see how i use instantiate item ...etc

P.S. my answer is very general because no details were provided